# Flatten columns by grouping by and adding values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like

```
 id, index, name, count1, count2
   1,   1,  foo, 12, 10
   1, 2,  foo,  11, 12
   1, 3, foo, 23, 12
   1, 1, bar, 11, 21
   ...
   2, 1, foo, ...
```

I want to get a dataframe as follows

```
id, name, count1, count2
1, foo, 46,34
1, bar, ..
```

So basically, i want to "washaway" index from this field.. while adding the count1 and count2 columns

How do i do this in pandas/python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is that what you want?

```
In [24]: df.groupby(['id','name']).sum().reset_index()
Out[24]:
   id name  index  count1  count2
0   1  bar      1      11      21
1   1  foo      6      46      34
```

if you want to drop `index` column:

```
In [26]: df.groupby(['id','name']).sum().reset_index().drop('index', 1)
Out[26]:
   id name  count1  count2
0   1  bar      11      21
1   1  foo      46      34
```

data:

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]:
   id  index name  count1  count2
0   1      1  foo      12      10
1   1      2  foo      11      12
2   1      3  foo      23      12
3   1      1  bar      11      21
```